# Failed to load the url firefox

Tags: css, codeigniter, firefox

I have loaded the css background image but it wont displayed in browser, am working in codeigniter framework. Am using firefox...

```
#star ul.star { 
list-style:none; 
margin:0; 
padding: 0; 
width:85px; 
height:20px; 
left: 10px; 
top:4px; 
position:relative; 
float:left; 
background:url('../media/stars.gif') repeat-x; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: online site..??so  i can have a look and fix it...

Comment: Did you inspect the Ul in Firefox.

Comment: Arun: No its in local

Comment: Varghese:s i have inspected the element using firebug.

Comment: I think you should check `PravinS` solution @naveen

Comment: I have checked varghese but again it thrown an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give absolute path of image for that or
if "media" folder is in root directory then you can use it like this

```
background:url('/media/stars.gif') repeat-x;
```

may this will help you

Comment: Failed to load the given url(firefox), i have inspected the element and it shows this error

Comment: if you "media" folder is at "application" folder level, then try using image path as "media/stars.gif"